# Having trouble positioning logo and nav bar

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I cannot seem to figure out how to get my website to look like my homework version. Can anyone help?

Homework version:

[image]

My version:

[image]

css:

[image]

html:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in the text of your question, not in an image. Putting your code in an image makes it hard to read and makes it less likely that you'll get help.

Comment: Theres so much here that needs needs styling - how can we possibly provide everything? We cannot do your homework for you!

Comment: Is your "homework" image on an actual web page, or is it an image?

Comment: No its just an image. I wish it were a webpage so I could just right click, and inspect.

Comment: Dude, you're ganna have to do the 'inspect' yourself. Open your inspector and make some changes to the nav. I would start with display inline block. Padding around the anchors, border-right at the list item, padding on the logo. Just keep adding until you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to add padding to 'logo' and get rid of that border on your unordered lists.

Comment: I am not referring to the padding, I am referring to the layout. I am trying to get the nav bar to move all the way to the right inline with the logo

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a padding around the container that has the logo and menu. You should also try `display: inline-block` so that they go on the same line. At the min, the logo takes up all the width, followed by the menu.